# Why is 'let x = 1' valid F# expression?

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

I am trying to write F# parser. According to the [specification](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html) the let expression looks like:

```
let value-defn in expr
```

I am using [Try F#](http://www.tryfsharp.org/Learn/getting-started) for testing. I tried following code which is parsed without error.

```
#light "off"
let a = 1
```

Yet according to the manual, should always contain **in** keyword. Why is it valid F# code?

Comment: The specification you've linked is full of examples of form `let x = y`.

Comment: The key thing is that standalone `let a = 1` is not an expression, but a valid top-level module definition (which can be used inside a module or in F# Interactive interactions).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually covered by another part of the spec (A.2.1.1)

> module-function-or-value-defn :
>
> ```
>   attributesopt let function-defn
>
>   attributesopt let value-defn
> ```

Since you are defining something in a module directly, it doesn't need the `in`